How to Use Occupancy Grid Map as Local Costmap for Move_base in TurtleBot3?
I’m working with ROS1 Noetic on Ubuntu 20.04 and am using a TurtleBot3 with 360 Laser Distance Sensor LDS-01 (for creating a map and global path planning). I want to create a local costmap from an occupancy grid map published on /robot_hld_classifier/map and use it with the move_base package for local path planning.
Setup Details:
Occupancy Grid Map Topic: /robot_hld_classifier/map

Value of 100 for completely occupied space
Value of 0 for free space
Intermediate values (0-100) for varying occupancy levels
Value of -1 for unknown space

I’ve modified turtlebot3_navigation.launch and move_base.launch files, and my local costmap configuration (modified_local_costmap.yaml) is as follows:
modified_turtlebot3_navigation.launch
<launch>
  <!-- Arguments -->
  <arg name="model" default="$(env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL)" doc="model type [burger, waffle, waffle_pi]"/>
  <arg name="map_file" default="/home/mi/Desktop/map_staffroom.yaml"/>
  <arg name="open_rviz" default="true"/>
  <arg name="move_forward_only" default="false"/>

  <!-- Turtlebot3 -->
  <include file="$(find turtlebot3_bringup)/launch/turtlebot3_remote.launch">
    <arg name="model" value="$(arg model)" />
  </include>

  <!-- Map server -->
  <node pkg="map_server" name="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)"/>

  <!-- AMCL -->
  <include file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/launch/amcl.launch"/>

  <!-- move_base -->
  <include file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/launch/modified_move_base.launch">
    <arg name="model" value="$(arg model)" />
    <arg name="move_forward_only" value="$(arg move_forward_only)"/>
  </include>

  <!-- rviz -->
  <group if="$(arg open_rviz)"> 
<node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" required="true"
      args="-d $(find turtlebot3_navigation)/rviz/turtlebot3_navigation.rviz"/>
  </group>
</launch>

modified_move_base.launch
<launch>
  <!-- Arguments -->
  <arg name="model" default="$(env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL)" doc="model type [burger, waffle, waffle_pi]"/>
  <arg name="cmd_vel_topic" default="/cmd_vel" />
  <arg name="odom_topic" default="odom" />
  <arg name="move_forward_only" default="false"/>

  <!-- move_base -->
  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <param name="base_local_planner" value="dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params_$(arg model).yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/modified_local_costmap.yaml" command="load" />
<rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/move_base_params.yaml" command="load" />
<rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/dwa_local_planner_params_$(arg model).yaml" command="load" />
<remap from="cmd_vel" to="$(arg cmd_vel_topic)"/>
    <remap from="odom" to="$(arg odom_topic)"/>
<param name="DWAPlannerROS/min_vel_x" value="0.0" if="$(arg move_forward_only)" />
  </node>
</launch>

modified_local_costmap.yaml
local_costmap:
  global_frame: odom
  robot_base_frame: base_footprint
  update_frequency: 10.0
  publish_frequency: 10.0
  transform_tolerance: 0.5
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  map_topic: "/robot_hld_classifier/map"
  subscribe_to_updates: true
  track_unknown_space: true
  unknown_cost_value: -1
  width: 4.0
  height: 4.0
  resolution: 0.02
  plugins:
    - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

inflation_layer:
  inflation_radius: 1.0
  cost_scaling_factor: 3.0

Launch Output:
Everything appears to load correctly. However, when I start the navigation, local path planning does not seem to work as expected.
... logging to /home/mi/.ros/log/dc22050a-a27c-11ef-ae32-73676f9bbf45/roslaunch-mi-workspace-36488.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

xacro: in-order processing became default in ROS Melodic. You can drop the option.
started roslaunch server http://192.168.1.118:37475/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /amcl/base_frame_id: base_footprint
 * /amcl/gui_publish_rate: 50.0
 * /amcl/initial_pose_a: 0.0
 * /amcl/initial_pose_x: 0.0
 * /amcl/initial_pose_y: 0.0
 * /amcl/kld_err: 0.02
 * /amcl/laser_lambda_short: 0.1
 * /amcl/laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
 * /amcl/laser_max_beams: 180
 * /amcl/laser_max_range: 3.5
 * /amcl/laser_model_type: likelihood_field
 * /amcl/laser_sigma_hit: 0.2
 * /amcl/laser_z_hit: 0.5
 * /amcl/laser_z_max: 0.05
 * /amcl/laser_z_rand: 0.5
 * /amcl/laser_z_short: 0.05
 * /amcl/max_particles: 3000
 * /amcl/min_particles: 500
 * /amcl/odom_alpha1: 0.1
 * /amcl/odom_alpha2: 0.1
 * /amcl/odom_alpha3: 0.1
 * /amcl/odom_alpha4: 0.1
 * /amcl/odom_frame_id: odom
 * /amcl/odom_model_type: diff
 * /amcl/recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
 * /amcl/recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
 * /amcl/resample_interval: 1
 * /amcl/transform_tolerance: 0.5
 * /amcl/update_min_a: 0.2
 * /amcl/update_min_d: 0.2
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/acc_lim_theta: 3.2
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/acc_lim_x: 2.5
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/acc_lim_y: 0.0
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/controller_frequency: 10.0
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/forward_point_distance: 0.325
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/goal_distance_bias: 20.0
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/latch_xy_goal_tolerance: False
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/max_scaling_factor: 0.2
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/max_vel_theta: 2.75
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/max_vel_trans: 0.22
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/max_vel_x: 0.22
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/max_vel_y: 0.0
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/min_vel_theta: 1.37
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/min_vel_trans: 0.11
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/min_vel_x: -0.22
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/min_vel_y: 0.0
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/occdist_scale: 0.02
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/path_distance_bias: 32.0
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/publish_cost_grid_pc: True
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/publish_traj_pc: True
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/scaling_speed: 0.25
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/sim_time: 1.5
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/stop_time_buffer: 0.2
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/vth_samples: 40
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/vx_samples: 20
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/vy_samples: 0
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/xy_goal_tolerance: 0.05
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.17
 * /move_base/base_local_planner: dwa_local_planner...
 * /move_base/conservative_reset_dist: 3.0
 * /move_base/controller_frequency: 10.0
 * /move_base/controller_patience: 15.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/footprint: [[-0.105, -0.105]...
 * /move_base/global_costmap/global_frame: map
 * /move_base/global_costmap/inflation_radius: 1.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/map_type: costmap
 * /move_base/global_costmap/observation_sources: scan
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_range: 3.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/publish_frequency: 10.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/raytrace_range: 3.5
 * /move_base/global_costmap/robot_base_frame: base_footprint
 * /move_base/global_costmap/scan/clearing: True
 * /move_base/global_costmap/scan/data_type: LaserScan
 * /move_base/global_costmap/scan/marking: True
 * /move_base/global_costmap/scan/sensor_frame: base_scan
 * /move_base/global_costmap/scan/topic: scan
 * /move_base/global_costmap/static_map: True
 * /move_base/global_costmap/transform_tolerance: 0.5
 * /move_base/global_costmap/update_frequency: 10.0
 * /move_base/inflation_layer/cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
 * /move_base/inflation_layer/inflation_radius: 1.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/global_frame: odom
 * /move_base/local_costmap/height: 4.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/map_topic: /robot_hld_classi...
 * /move_base/local_costmap/origin_x: 2.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/plugins: [{'name': 'inflat...
 * /move_base/local_costmap/publish_frequency: 10.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/resolution: 0.02
 * /move_base/local_costmap/robot_base_frame: base_footprint
 * /move_base/local_costmap/rolling_window: True
 * /move_base/local_costmap/static_map: False
 * /move_base/local_costmap/subscribe_to_updates: True
 * /move_base/local_costmap/track_unknown_space: True
 * /move_base/local_costmap/transform_tolerance: 0.5
 * /move_base/local_costmap/unknown_cost_value: -1
 * /move_base/local_costmap/update_frequency: 10.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/width: 4.0
 * /move_base/oscillation_distance: 0.2
 * /move_base/oscillation_timeout: 10.0
 * /move_base/planner_frequency: 5.0
 * /move_base/planner_patience: 5.0
 * /move_base/shutdown_costmaps: False
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /robot_state_publisher/publish_frequency: 50.0
 * /robot_state_publisher/tf_prefix: 
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.17.0

NODES
  /
    amcl (amcl/amcl)
    map_server (map_server/map_server)
    move_base (move_base/move_base)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
    rviz (rviz/rviz)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.118:11311

process[robot_state_publisher-1]: started with pid [36504]
process[map_server-2]: started with pid [36505]
process[amcl-3]: started with pid [36506]
process[move_base-4]: started with pid [36507]
process[rviz-5]: started with pid [36517]
[ WARN] [1731584778.101289050]: global_costmap: Pre-Hydro parameter "static_map" unused since "plugins" is provided
[ WARN] [1731584778.104913292]: global_costmap: Pre-Hydro parameter "map_type" unused since "plugins" is provided
[ INFO] [1731584778.106191761]: global_costmap: Using plugin "static_layer"
[ INFO] [1731584778.121213555]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [1731584778.330141569]: Resizing costmap to 384 X 384 at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1731584778.429826064]: Received a 384 X 384 map at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1731584778.438539819]: global_costmap: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[ INFO] [1731584778.446082828]:     Subscribed to Topics: scan
[ INFO] [1731584778.470803235]: global_costmap: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[ WARN] [1731584778.536830359]: local_costmap: Pre-Hydro parameter "static_map" unused since "plugins" is provided
[ INFO] [1731584778.539320009]: local_costmap: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[ INFO] [1731584778.609957304]: Created local_planner dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS
[ INFO] [1731584778.623354015]: Sim period is set to 0.10
[ INFO] [1731584778.811499811]: Recovery behavior will clear layer 'obstacles'
[ INFO] [1731584778.822124612]: Recovery behavior will clear layer 'obstacles'
[ INFO] [1731584778.877805121]: odom received!


What I’ve Tried:

Verified that the /robot_hld_classifier/map topic is active and publishing nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid messages.
Set map_topic in the local costmap to /robot_hld_classifier/map to use my custom occupancy grid map for local planning.


Question:
How can I set up move_base to use my occupancy grid map as a local costmap for path planning? Is there something I’m missing in my configuration?
Updated:
I now use the configuration below to create the local costmap, and the local costmap is successfully published. However, it seems to be using the /map topic from map_server instead of the custom topic /robot_hld_classifier/map as intended. (The /robot_hld_classifier/map is generated from depth camera data in front of the robot, so its costmap should display only the region directly ahead of the robot.)
local_costmap:
  global_frame: odom
  robot_base_frame: base_footprint
  update_frequency: 10.0
  publish_frequency: 10.0
  transform_tolerance: 0.5
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 4.0
  height: 4.0
  resolution: 0.02
  
  plugins:
    - {name: terrain_layer, type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
    - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
    
terrain_layer:
  map_topic: "/robot_hld_classifier/map"
  subscribe_to_updates: true
  track_unknown_space: true
  unknown_cost_value: -1

inflation_layer:
  inflation_radius: 1.0
  cost_scaling_factor: 3.0



Updated Question:
How can I configure the costmap to properly use the /robot_hld_classifier/map topic as its source instead of /map? Is there any additional configuration or debugging step I am missing?

You should be using the static_layer plugin for the move_base Local Costmap, and it should be the first layer.
You must provide accurate frame_id info so that the spatial relationship between your data and the (global) map frame can be determined. Assuming you have rolling_window set to true, the local costmap code will use the robot's current map x,y position (not pose!) and the costmap dimensions to select a small region from the larger map you provide.

I followed the steps you suggested, and the costmap is now running. However, it seems to be using the /map topic instead of the custom topic I intended to use, which is /robot_hld_classifier/map. Could you advise on how I can configure move_base or the costmap parameters to ensure it uses my /robot_hld_classifier/map topic instead of /map?

Is your map_topic property a child of the static_layer configuration? It should not be an immediate child of local_costmap like you show above.

I have already set the map_topic, which is /robot_hld_classifier/map, as a child of the static_layer. However, it still pulls /map from the map_server instead. I have verified that /robot_hld_classifier/map is still active.

We use this feature with our robots in noetic, so I know it works. Please edit your post to append your new local_costmap config (Keep the original so future readers can see it.)

Thank you very much for your kind suggestion. I’ve updated the post to include the new local_costmap configuration while keeping the original for reference. I’d greatly appreciate it if you could take a look and help me troubleshoot this issue.

From your rviz image, we can not determine what obstacles are from global_costmap vs. those from local_costmap. To debug: do not display global_costmap in rviz, also disable inflation layer (enabled: false). Then I suggest you read the wiki page on how subscribe_to_updates works: https://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro/staticmap
